# Datatable update in different thread (WPF)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable, multithreading

I have a Datatable assigned to a DataGrid in main thread. I am updating the same DataTable  from two different thread classes. Although the rows gets updated successfully in DataGrid  control, I get following execption:

> NotSupportedException thrown, with the
>   message saying 'This type of
>   CollectionView does not support
>   changes to its SourceCollection from a
>   thread different from the Dispatcher
>   thread.'

Any ideas on how do i update the DataTable in different thread?

Abdul khaliq

Answer (score 0):

from the thread you have your CollectionView in, use

```
this.Invoke(myUpdateMethod);

public void myUpdateMethod()
{

// get data from different thread and update collectionView

}
```